# Oracle Apex 20.1 automated testing

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is there available any tool or framework for automated security testing of Oracle Apex 20.1 application?

I found Apex-sert but as the README on their github page says it supports only older versions.

https://github.com/OraOpenSource/apex-sert

Answer (score 1):

You can download from my fork https://github.com/rajeshvig/apex-sert, last build is for 19.1 but i didn't have to make any changes till 20.2 after this as it works as is

Answer (score 0):

No, There is no tool or framework for automated security testing of Oracle Apex 20.1 application as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen an automation tool specific for APEX, however there are some that are surprisingly capable or navigating it in and have a low learning curve.

Have you ever tried [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) ? We use it here and it does the trick with APEX and many other types of web applications.

If you never heard of it, I could recommend [this video from insum](https://www.insum.ca/advanced-apex-ui-test-automation-with-cypress/)

Answer (score -1):

Since recently we published APEX SERT for APEX 19.x, 20.x, 21.x and 22.x

You can find more details here https://lschilde.blogspot.com/2023/03/apex-sert-for-apex-191-apex-192-apex.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).